# NAOqi No subscription found for SignalLink

Tags: python, python-2.7, robotics, nao-robot, pepper

I am trying to record an audio file from the robot pepper and store it on my local machine, I tried to use these two approaches:

Here I used NAOqi with ALAudioDevice and ALAudioRecorder but I didn't get any outputs the code exits with no errors:

```
import naoqi
import qi
from naoqi import ALProxy 
from time import sleep 

ROBOT_IP = '192.168.0.169'
ROBOT_PORT = 9559

# sound = ALProxy("ALAudioDevice" , ROBOT_IP, ROBOT_PORT)
sound = ALProxy("ALAudioRecorder" , ROBOT_IP, ROBOT_PORT)

# sound.startMicrophonesRecording("/tmp/pepper/test.wav")
sound.startMicrophonesRecording("/tmp/pepper/test.wav","wav",16000,[0,0,1,0])

sleep(3)

sound.stopMicrophonesRecording()
```

but here I did the same thing using qi and I also tried both ALAudioDevice and ALAudioRecorder like this:

```
import naoqi
import qi
from naoqi import ALProxy 
from time import sleep 

ROBOT_IP = '192.168.0.169'
ROBOT_PORT = 9559

session = qi.Session()
    
connection_url = "tcp://" + ROBOT_IP + ":" + str(ROBOT_PORT)
session.connect(connection_url)

sound = session.service("ALAudioDevice")
# sound = session.service("ALAudioRecorder")

sound.startMicrophonesRecording("/tmp/pepper/test.wav")
# sound.startMicrophonesRecording("/tmp/pepper/test.wav","wav",16000,[0,0,1,0])

sleep(3)

tts.stopMicrophonesRecording()
```

this is the output and still I don't get any recorded aurdio.

> [W] 1615812775.715142 775 qi.path.sdklayout: No Application was created, trying to deduce paths
> [W] 1615812776.325653 10499 qitype.signal: disconnect: No subscription found for SignalLink 0.
> [W] 1615812776.325654 2819 qitype.signal: disconnect: No subscription found for SignalLink 13.

I would appreciate any help or resources to get the desired recorded audio and saved on my local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ALAudioRecorder](https://developer.softbankrobotics.com/pepper-naoqi-25/naoqi-developer-guide/naoqi-apis/naoqi-audio/alaudiorecorder/alaudiorecorder-api) produces a sound file *on the robot*.
To collect it, you will have to use `scp`. In your case, to put the file in your downloads folder:

```sh
scp nao@ROBOT_IP:/tmp/pepper/test.wav ~/Downloads/test.wav
```

There is also an alternative: you can [get the sound buffers directly](https://developer.softbankrobotics.com/pepper-naoqi-25/naoqi-developer-guide/other-tutorials/python-sdk-tutorials/python-sdk-examples-1-0).

The logs you have seen are unrelated to your issue, this is just some pollution from the framework.